Why Bone not Moving With Mesh Even When weight painted?
So i just parent the character to the bone with Automatic weights, then the body starts moving with the bone, then all of a sudden i find out that the fingers are not moving with the bones properly like this:
any solution?



Hello, probably the vertices are shared by several vertex groups, maybe share your file so that we can check?

Uploading it right now, BRB

so i just use WorkUpload take a look https://workupload.com/file/eaEAKRetk2n

As you see, the whole hand is assigned to the vertex group called hand.R, just remove the finger vertices from this vertex group and it will work great:


imma try that out, BRB

Hey, that works, thanks for the help

@CoreRageEntertainment If this answer solved your problem you can accept it, see What should I do when someone answers my question?
